# Asking for some Error

Tags: php

I've got error
when i fill the form and click the submit
the result was error "Data Gagal Di tambahkan"
Here the code

```
<?php
include 'koneksi/koneksi.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
$nis                    = $_POST['nis'];
$nama                   = $_POST['nama'];
$kelas                  = $_POST['kelas'];
$nilai_ulangan_teori    = $_POST['nilai_ulangan_teori'];
$nilai_ulangan_praktek  = $_POST['nilai_ulangan_praktek'];

$sql    = "INSERT INTO t_siswa VALUES ('$nis',
        '$nama',
        '$kelas',
        '$nilai_ulangan_teori',
        '$nilai_ulangan_praktek'
        )";
$nilai  ="($nilai_ulangan_teori + $nilai_ulangan_praktek)/2";
if (mysql_query($sql)){
    header("location:index.php");
} else {
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">alert("Data gagal ditambahkan");</script>';
}
}
```

here the connection

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "db_uas_pwd_2017";

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db);

$mysqli = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
```

Comment: i forgot, for $nilai
don't count it. i forgot to delete it

Comment: include your table structure

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection. **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: That's not how we insert data, check this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: use `mysql_error()` to find out the error message

Comment: i've tried use mysqli_*
but i got error too


Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\uaspwd\koneksi\koneksi.php on line 8



Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\uaspwd\tambah.php on line 19

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL code is wrong. You need to specify the column names in the SQL code. For example, the SQL should look something like this

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

And, mysql_ has been depreciated and now PHP recommends either using mysqli_ or PDO. For more references, visit the links below :

- https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

**Answer from xXAlphaManXx, 15yr old**